# Provisioning profile & signing issue

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I am having a signing issue when trying to send an update to iTunes Connect for an iOS app.

For the: Signing (Release) I choose a Provisioning profile `Provis_AppStore` which is a distribution profile. It uses a Distribution certificate.

And I get this problem:

> Provisioning profile "Provis_AppStore" doesn't include signing
>   certificate "iPhone Developer: My Name (A1B2C35XY)".

What is the solution here? And why do I get this message about "iPhone Developer" when my profile is signed with a distribution certificate?

Note that before making this post, I have tried "Automatically manage signing" as I recently do most of the time to avoid this kind of issue. But (this app probably being an old one), it did not work.

Precisely, if I want to use *Automatically manage signing*; this what I get:

```
    WARNING ITMS-90076: "Potential Loss of Keychain Access.
The previous version of software has an application-identifier
 value of ['A1B2C3D4.my.name.software.MyApp'] and the new 
version of software being submitted has an application-identifier
 of ['X6Y7Z8W9.my.name.software.MyApp']. This will result in a
 loss of keychain access."
```

Comment: it seems like your signing certificate is not in your keychain. Did you create this distribution certificate on this machine? Is your account a personal membership or a company one?

Comment: My account is a personal one. Beside I don't think this certificate has been created on another machine?

Comment: what is the story of the app? and did you try what is written here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1726/_index.html

Comment: Does your app use the keychain? If not then just move to automatic signing.

Comment: As far as I know it does not. Could it be that it uses it without me being aware of that?
Beside, I have tried to go ahead and see what happens with Automatically manage signing. But I see the warning shown in my post. And though I do the upload I never see the build appear in itunes connect after that.